# Firebase sign in anonymously in Unity Editor with same UserId

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

The recently released Firebase SDK 4.5.0 for Unity is now supported in Editor mode, which is great!
However, when using the SigninAnynouslyAsync() method from Editor, the UserID is not kept persistent like it is when called from iOS/device.
Does anyone know how to preserve the UserId for this method running from the Editor?
I guess the UserId is stored somewhere in Persistent store on device, but is it possible to set some kind of parameter to simulate this behavior from the Editor?